# How to add more variables to a jquery library without modifying it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using "jQuery-v2.0.3 AND jQueryUI-v1.11.3" in my existing project. There is one function in jQueryUI file like:

```
function n() {
        ..........., 
        this.regional = [], 
        this.regional[""] = {
            .....,
            monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
            dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
            dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
            .......
        }, 
        ........
    }
```

Is it possible to add few more variables like "this.regional["nl"] = {....}" without modifying this file? I want to use an another JS file which must be able to append new variables to that function so that I can escaped from modifying the jquery-ui library? OR is there any other equivalent way ?

Comment: If that function is exposed as a method you may be able to monkeypatch it. If not, I don't think there's a way to do what you want.

Comment: You might want to look at how `datetimepicker` has modified the behavior of `datepicker`.

Comment: I don't think it is exposed. In library also it is declared as function n(){---}

Comment: Did you try the prototype approach ?

Comment: No I didn't tried that. I am not aware what is prototype approach. Very new in UI stuff.